How to read from SQLite3 database to create PWA dashboard?
I have a legacy windows software that writes to an SQLlite3 database. I need to read this database and present the data on a web application or android app dashboard after some calculation.
The reading from the database should be triggered whenever the legacy software writes on it. i.e. we need live data from the database to be presented on the tablet app.
the tablet is android, that app could be native android app or PWA or even else.
I can install anything on the windows machine (windows10, Bit64)
The table will be on the same LAN
The legacy software get the data from some sensors and write it into it's .db3 file.
what is the best or possible approach to build a solution?
I expect the mobile app or web app displaying the data needed in a nice dashboard instantly.

As you said - it is on same LAN. In that case the simplest way is create a share on the machine where the DB file is. Then create background process in your application to check on the DB file modification and query the data you need to monitor from the endpoind application.
In addition, SQLite has triggers. You can add a triger for the table(s) which are  changing and have that triger to modify something; for example a table where is only one field and one record - a timestamp or an incremtal and then monitor that to dermine a change.
If that is not an option you may implement a webserver and create a site which will advertise the change and or data.
There are several frameworks for http access to sqlite (over REST api): Slim, Lumen, Laravel, Flight, Phalcon

Thank you for answer.
If you can give more details on the Background process. Is it shell script? if you can give an example.
For the webserver woudn't that be slow? I need the response to be instant lest than 2sec.

It depends on the application you are using to read the data. Every 2 seconds is certainly achiavable, but again that depends on the network and the place where the DB is stored and speed of the endpoint. If you need to present on web application, best is read the data directly from the file. If possible I would run the webserver on the machine where is the DB. Point your script directly to it and display the result or use the preformated output or JSON data wherever else.
